# How to have different layouts for different screen sizes in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, uiview, storyboard

I'm having a lot of trouble with the layout out my first app. I'm designing it for the iPhone 10 and it looks great, but whenever I try to use auto constraints (which I'm still very new to) it doesn't look great. Ideally, I want to have a completely different design/elements depending on the iPhone of user  that I could edit individually in the storyboard. Is this possible? If not, what is my best bet for constraints? here is an image of the layout of my app. each of these "tiles" are png's with 2-3 text labels on them

layout of app: https://gyazo.com/67bca9bd62be95fc0b69a70b74ddee6c

Comment: Have you tried playing around with stack views yet?

Comment: Hey, you just try setting each component with the auto constraints center horizontally and vertically and equal width and height then just change multiplier of that all constraints for exact size and poistion.

Comment: Seems that a collectionView should do the work for the design that you have. About the constraints. You can always check the screen size and pass the layout depending on its value. But beware, this is not a good practice and it will always come back to bite you.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla That would be very hard in a collection view I think... Better to use a stackview for the 3 vertical components in the bottom, on top of that another stackview which holds the other 2 components and a normal uiview for the top component.

Comment: @J.Doe, yes. It's true. I just think collectionViews can give more flexibility. Specially when changing the layout later on. From my point of view, reusability is also much easier with collectionView. But yes, there are several ways of doing it. It just depends on what it will be used for